# Can't use laptop's numpad even after turn on emulate numpad

Tags: interface, error

It's really a nightmare whenever i use blender.
I can't type any number key in blender even after turn on emulate numpad.
Is there anyone can help me solve this problem
i'm using Dell laptop (Inspiron 14-3467)

*can't type number key*
[image: can't type number key]

[image: emulate numpad but still usless]